# Help! How to deal with Mirror Sites

Tags: copyright, mirror

Someone sneakily copied part of the contents on our website and made a mirror website that looks almost like ours! This will be real confusing for many people and I am worrying this will lead to many other illegal acts and our visitors might be conned. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What country are you in, and what country is the Mirror site in? Has a significant portion of the site been copied? If yes and the mirror site is monetizing off your content, or has advertisements up generating revenue. You can file a DMCA

Comment: Pretty sure DMCA only applies to U.S.-hosted sites, but they apply regardless of ads or commercial intent. So long as they're copying copyrighted content, and the perpetrator's site is hosted in the U.S., a DMCA takedown notice should work.

Comment: The hosting of my website is Japan, and the copy cat is hosted in America

Comment: @Lèsemajesté you can fight a DMCA if your sites content is protected under fair use two examples are paypalsucks dot com and boycottgillette dot com.